# How receive xml code without AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax

In an app that i'am creating i have to receive from the server an xml string with this format eg: `<reply>
           <script>
                alert('Hello World!');
           </script>
     </reply>` 
when i did this using ajax work perferct, but when i try to receive the data in an iframe i can't extract the data from the frame because is not there, IE and FF open new tabs and append the data on that tab, how i avoid that and makes them insert the data on the frame.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have right now?

Comment: I don't have a code yet, that data is the response of the server that will be 'target' on the iframe, but the problem is that the only browser that insert the data on the iframe is Chrome the others open a new tab and insert the data.

This is the code of the frame:"<iframe id='frame_trgt' />"

Comment: @hidura, if you are posting updated code, edit your question and add it there, more clear and effective at communicating WHAT you want.

Comment: Can you not convert it to html on the (or another) server?

Comment: @mplungjan I receive the data as plain/text because i have to passed that data to a function and there append the result to the HTML document.

Comment: I have a big problem to receive the data in xml from the server when i not using AJAX

Comment: So use a proxy that gathers the data and transforms it on your server into something you can use

Comment: I solve this problem, i will create a file xml and send an script with an AJAX call that will read the file, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can do this work still using Javascript, get the result of the ajax and write it inside the iframe:

1. first create your iframe tag like this:
2. than the javascript code to insert the ajax:

   var t = document.getElementById('iftarget');

   h = t.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('html');

   h[0].innerHTML = '<h1>Hello</h1> This must work! Put your data here';

I have created a jsFiddle for this
http://jsfiddle.net/nunomazer/JGyEr/

Best Regards